# How to display selected rows in datagridview to crystal report

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, datagridview, crystal-reports

This is my first time using Crystal reports.I have a store procedure and What i am trying to do is when i highlight a row in `datagridview` and click report button, that only the highlighted row gets sent to the report viewer page.I have tried some solutions here but no luck.

Report button code

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine

Public Class frmView
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DBSAS;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim a As New OpenFileDialog

    Private Sub btnRep_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRep.Click 
            cn.Open()
        Dim report As New ReportDocument
        da.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("EXEC usplatestDateEnrolled ", cn)
        report.RecordSelectionFormula = "{@studID}" & dgv1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value
        report.Load("C:\users\agent_edx44\My Documents\Visual studio 2012\projects\SASApp\Rep.rpt")
        frmReport.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report
        frmReport.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
        frmReport.Show()
            cn.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Store Procedure code

```
USE [DbSAS]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[uspLatestDateEnrolled]    Script Date: 02/07/2016 12:35:26 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspLatestDateEnrolled]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

@studID INT = NULL


AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT sh.SchoolYear,
        sh.Levels,sh.Section, sh.DateEnrolled ,
        SI.StudentID,SI.Surname,SI.FirstName,SI.MiddleName, SI.StudAddress , 
        SI.BirthDay,SI.Gender, SI.Nationality, SI.BirthPlace,
        SI.TelNum,SI.SchoolWhereGraduated , 
        SI.DatesWhenGraduated, SI.SchoolLastAttended,
        SI.SchoolAddress, SI.Note,SI.StudImage,
        PI.Father_FirstName,PI.Father_LastName,
        PI.Father_MI,PI.Father_Occupation, 
        PI.Father_TelNUm, PI.Mother_FirstName, PI.Mother_LastName,
        PI.Mother_MI,PI.Mother_Occupation,PI.Mother_TelNum,
        PI.Contact_FirstName,PI.Contact_LastName,PI.Contact_MI,
        PI.Contact_Mobile,PI.Contact_TelNum,PI.Contact_Address  
        FROM StudentInformation SI 
        JOIN StudentHistory SH  
            ON SI.StudentID = SH.StudentID
        JOIN ParentInformation PI
        ON PI.ParentID = SI.ParentID
        WHERE si.StudentID = @studID
        ORDER BY DateEnrolled DESC

            SELECT * FROM StudentHistory WHERE StudentID = @studID
                ORDER BY DateEnrolled DESC
            SELECT TOP 1 SchoolYear,
                Levels,Section, DateEnrolled as LatestDate
                FROM StudentHistory
                WHERE studentID = @studID
                ORDER BY DateEnrolled DESC
```

When i run this code it says that

> Invalid report file path in this line

```
report.RecordSelectionFormula = "{@studID}" & dgv1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value
```

Can anyone help me to fix my code. I'm stuck here for almost an hour. Thanks in advance

Comment: where are you passing value to stored procedure?

Comment: @Siva I want to pass it to my crystal report so that only the selected data will appear on my crystal report viewer page.  Can you help me to do that?

Comment: I am not well versed with code but this may help you..try like this....report.RecordSelectionFormula = "{@studID}" & "-" & dgv1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value

Comment: @Siva Thanks for the reply but it produces same error.. I'm stuck in here for almost 10 hours. I hope someone can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: I have made a mistake try now report.RecordSelectionFormula = "{@studID}" & "= & dgv1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value

Comment: @Siva , I have this error now [Error Image](http://img6.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/22071/2207196690be0aa4978b94ae0b10df631e8c8b9c.png) Can you please check my code if i am in the right path?

Comment: You are missing double quote ot should be like this "=" not like this "=

Comment: @Siva I put now the double quote but it displays same error.. [Image](http://img3.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/22072/22072233766c3d69f4d941f6916ee705aabc00cb.png)

Comment: Is the report present in the file path C:\users\agent_edx44\My Documents\Visual studio 2012\projects\SASApp\Rep.rpt

Comment: @Siva Yes.. It is present. I double check it now.

Comment: I am sorry..not sure what is the issue may be others can help

Comment: @Siva thanks for the effort to help me.. I hope someone can help me to solve this..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding .ToString on the end of this line:

```
report.RecordSelectionFormula = "{@studID}" & dgv1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value
```